# Problemas con mostrar tabla de datos simbolicos en Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ciencia-de-datos

Estoy creando una aplicación web con Shiny. El problema que tengo que es que al momento de generar una tabla de datos simbólicos y querer mostrarla en Shiny, no me muestra el nombre de los objetos simbólicos. Me muestra el nombre de las variables al utilizar la función para graficar la tabla, pero no me muestra el nombre de los objetos simbólicos, cosa que si lo hago en un script en R lo hace normalmente.

Dejo el fragmento de código. Gracias!

Esto es el fragmento que se encuentra dentro del archivo server.r

```
output$resultado<- renderTable ({
   file1 <<- input$file
   if(is.null(file1)){return()}
  variable <<- read.table(file=file1$datapath,sep=input$sep,header=input$header,stringsAsFactors= input$stringsAsFactors)
     result<-classic.to.sym(data =variable,concept =input$variablenom,variables =names(variable))
     display.sym.table(result)
 })
```

Y esto es la parte del archivo ui.r

```
mainPanel(
    uiOutput("tb"),
    tableOutput("resultado")
  )
```

Comment: Hola @user133556  no he podido reproducir tu ejemplo. Hay varios input de los cuales tengo que suponer el tipo. También hay algunas funciones que no se de donde provienen supuse que del paquete RSDA... ojala me puedas ayudar para reproducir el ejemplo. Saludos